# Google Calendar Api

Tags: javascript, api, google, token, google-calendar

Estou tendo problemas com o Access Token do Google Calendar.
O problema é o seguinte. Eu tenho que sincronizar o calendário da minha aplicação com o Google Calendar, sendo que, usuários irão fornecer os emails deles para autenticação do google, que irá fornecer o token para que terceiros possam incluir eventos na agendo do usuário que autorizou o serviço. 
Quando já tenho acesso ao token de algum usuário e o uso para fazer todo esse processo, o token funciona por um determinado período, pois ele reseta.

O problema é, como posso usar esse access token sem esse problema, visto que ficar resetando este token toda vez que há uma inclusão de evento, excederá o número de vezes que o token pode ser resetado?

Existe alguma forma de tornar este token estático, ou sempre que houver a reset do toquem, eu consumi-lo novamente?

PS: Quando vou fazer o `includi` de um evento, estou usando Ajax com o access token dinâmico e id da agenda também.

Ex.:

```
var url = 'https://www.googleapis.com/calendar/v3/calendars/'+ meuidagenda@gmail.com +'/events?sendNotifications=false&access_token=' + access_token;

$.ajax({
    url: url,
    contentType: "application/json",
    data: JSON.stringify(resource),
    method : 'POST'
});
```

Comment: Veja as regras  de expiração do token do google, talvez ajude. https://developers.google.com/identity/protocols/OAuth2#expiration